# Route two different dns's to same ip but different routes

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am struggling with this and after googling it for hours figured it would be better to ask here to get more clarity on what I am trying to do.

So I have two domains pointing at the same server.
What I want is for one domain to point at a route such as /example1 and the other domain to point at another route such as /example2

Does anyone have insight on how to best accomplish this?
We are using WSO2 API Manager which is an open source platform.

Comment: This isn't a DNS problem; it's a web server **virtual host** problem.

Comment: What's your usecase? How you are going to decide which domain need to be invoked?

Comment: based on the route /store or /publisher

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using a reverse proxy such as NginX. Following sample config might help. You should also be able to go through NginX config docs and figure things out. Some of the config lines in the below config may not be needed. But I am not sure since I am not a NginX expert.

```
    server {
           listen   443;
           server_name apistore.alex.org;

           location / {
                   proxy_pass https://your-up-stream/store/;
                   proxy_redirect  https://your-up-stream/store/ /;
                   proxy_redirect  https://apistore.alex.org/store/ /;
                   proxy_cookie_path /store/ /;
           }
##You need to add the ssl certificate stuff here
    }
```

If you get above working, you can add a similar virtual-host for apipublisher.alex.org to pass it to the publisher app.

Note that, above config may not work out of the box. You need to add an upstream as well. I just wanted to tell that its possible to do this.